# What's the expected number of groups of 3 where all hate each other?

Tags: probability

There’s a party with 100 people at it. For each pair of people at the party,
those people either both like each other or both hate each other with 50/50 probability.
I'm thinking there are 5 distinct outcomes all with equal probability. Therefore the answer should be $\frac{100}{3}*\frac{1}{5}$.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an easier way of thinking about it:

There will be a total of
$$\binom{100}{3}$$
groups of three people at the party. For any group of three, the probability that its people are "pairwise hateful" is
$$\frac{1}{2^3}$$
since there are three pairs of people in a group of three. Thus $\frac{1}{8}$ of the groups of three people are expected to be "pairwise hateful" and so the total expected number of such groups is
$$\frac{1}{8}\binom{100}{3}$$

**WARNING:** As @Jaap observed in the comments, the groups are not independent, so this approach won't always work... however, due to the linearity of expectation, everything works out well in this case.

Comment: The groups are not independent (if two groups share two people, there are only 5 relationships instead of 6). Fortunately, that does not matter because of the [Linearity of Expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Ah, I just love it when things work out so nicely like that...

Comment: I don't fully understand Jaap's comment. Is it saying there are not $\binom{100}{3}$ groups of people or that the probability a group is hateful is $\frac{1}{8}$? What I'm guessing is that the probability a group is hateful is not $\frac{1}{8}$ because a person can't like someone if the other person hates them so whether a person hates someone is dependent on if the other person hates them too.

Comment: @rondon. No I think that Jaap is pointing that any two people will be in multiple groups of 3 (98 groups). If two people like each other in one group they will like each in all 98 groups. BTW, the way you've defined the problem you can't have one person like another, while the other hates the first.

Comment: @Nilknarf suggest you update your answer to include Jaap's observation (groups are not independent).

Comment: @rondon: Suppose you have two overlapping groups, one with people A,B,C, one with B,C,D. If A,B,C all like each other, then B,C,D cannot all hate each other. So knowledge of the relationships of one group will affect the probabilities of the other group. The events "ABC all hate each other" and "BCD all hate each other" are not independent events. Nevertheless, for expectation that does not matter. Let $X_{ABC}$ be a random variable that is 1 if ABC hate each other. Similarly $X_{BCD}$. Then $E(X_{ABC}+X_{BCD})=E(X_{ABC})+E(X_{BCD})=1/8+1/8=1/4$. Except you have $\binom{100}{3}$ groups, not 2.